# Android - Rotate video frames before sending to Wowza Streaming Engine using WebRTC

Tags: android, java-native-interface, webrtc, wowza

I want to stream video from android camera to Wowza Streaming Engine (WSE) using WebRTC. When device in landscape mode, everything work well. Then I try to stream by putting the device in portrait mode.

The first thing I notice in WSE player is the video stream has been rotated 90 counter-clockwise. I figured out that WebRTC do not rotate each video frame that comes out from ***onPreviewFrame*** API before sending to WSE and unfortunately WSE do not support any mechanisms to rotate video frame at their side at least so far.

So I checked out WebRTC android native source code and modify it to rotate each video frame before sending to WSE. And right now I can see the video stream in portrait mode in WSE player.

But it has an issue is sometimes video stream look so weird. Please see the following images.

[A normal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADS31.png)

[A weird image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZJ2D.png)

I put camera to a fix position. At the first time WSE player displays the first one, but sometimes the second one is showed up.

And here is the file in WebRTC source code that I changed.
***~/webrtc/src/sdk/android/src/jni/androidvideotracksource.cc***

```
void AndroidVideoTrackSource::OnByteBufferFrameCaptured(const void* frame_data,
                                                        int length,
                                                        int width,
                                                        int height,
                                                        VideoRotation rotation,
                                                        int64_t timestamp_ns) {
  RTC_DCHECK(camera_thread_checker_.CalledOnValidThread());

  int64_t camera_time_us = timestamp_ns / rtc::kNumNanosecsPerMicrosec;
  int64_t translated_camera_time_us =
      timestamp_aligner_.TranslateTimestamp(camera_time_us, rtc::TimeMicros());

  int adapted_width;
  int adapted_height;
  int crop_width;
  int crop_height;
  int crop_x;
  int crop_y;

  if (!AdaptFrame(width, height, camera_time_us, &adapted_width,
                  &adapted_height, &crop_width, &crop_height, &crop_x,
                  &crop_y)) {
    return;
  }

  const uint8_t* y_plane = static_cast<const uint8_t*>(frame_data);
  const uint8_t* uv_plane = y_plane + width * height;
  const int uv_width = (width + 1) / 2;

  RTC_CHECK_GE(length, width * height + 2 * uv_width * ((height + 1) / 2));

  // Can only crop at even pixels.
  crop_x &= ~1;
  crop_y &= ~1;
  // Crop just by modifying pointers.
  y_plane += width * crop_y + crop_x;
  uv_plane += uv_width * crop_y + crop_x;

  rtc::scoped_refptr<I420Buffer> buffer =
      buffer_pool_.CreateBuffer(adapted_width, adapted_height);

  nv12toi420_scaler_.NV12ToI420Scale(
      y_plane, width, uv_plane, uv_width * 2, crop_width, crop_height,
      buffer->MutableDataY(), buffer->StrideY(),
      // Swap U and V, since we have NV21, not NV12.
      buffer->MutableDataV(), buffer->StrideV(), buffer->MutableDataU(),
      buffer->StrideU(), buffer->width(), buffer->height());

  // TODO: Rotate I420 frame 90 degrees clockwise.
  rtc::scoped_refptr<I420Buffer> rotated_buffer =
      I420Buffer::Rotate(*buffer, kVideoRotation_90);

  OnFrame(VideoFrame(rotated_buffer, rotation, translated_camera_time_us));
}
```

I added this line of code to rotate I420 frame 90 degrees clockwise.

```
// TODO: Rotate I420 frame 90 degrees clockwise.
  rtc::scoped_refptr<I420Buffer> rotated_buffer =
      I420Buffer::Rotate(*buffer, kVideoRotation_90);
```

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you use Wowza Streaming Engine (WSE)  for free?

Is your application steam a live video from one device to others?

I'm looking for something like this, can you help me please,
Thank you

Comment: We were using WSE in production. My app stream from a device to another through WSE. What is your problem?

Comment: Is WSE free? Thanks

Comment: No, they have a trial version in 30 days, find more here https://www.wowza.com/pricing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have figured out a solution to solve this problem. Below are my steps:

**Step 1:** Make sure you lock your streaming activity to portrait orientation

**Step 2:** Change this method in the file in WebRTC android native source code
***~/webrtc/src/sdk/android/src/jni/androidvideotracksource.cc***

**Original Version:**

```
void AndroidVideoTrackSource::OnByteBufferFrameCaptured(const void* frame_data,
                                                        int length,
                                                        int width,
                                                        int height,
                                                        VideoRotation rotation,
                                                        int64_t timestamp_ns) {
  RTC_DCHECK(camera_thread_checker_.CalledOnValidThread());

  int64_t camera_time_us = timestamp_ns / rtc::kNumNanosecsPerMicrosec;
  int64_t translated_camera_time_us =
      timestamp_aligner_.TranslateTimestamp(camera_time_us, rtc::TimeMicros());

  int adapted_width;
  int adapted_height;
  int crop_width;
  int crop_height;
  int crop_x;
  int crop_y;

  if (!AdaptFrame(width, height, camera_time_us, &adapted_width,
                  &adapted_height, &crop_width, &crop_height, &crop_x,
                  &crop_y)) {
    return;
  }

  const uint8_t* y_plane = static_cast<const uint8_t*>(frame_data);
  const uint8_t* uv_plane = y_plane + width * height;
  const int uv_width = (width + 1) / 2;

  RTC_CHECK_GE(length, width * height + 2 * uv_width * ((height + 1) / 2));

  // Can only crop at even pixels.
  crop_x &= ~1;
  crop_y &= ~1;
  // Crop just by modifying pointers.
  y_plane += width * crop_y + crop_x;
  uv_plane += uv_width * crop_y + crop_x;

  rtc::scoped_refptr<I420Buffer> buffer =
      buffer_pool_.CreateBuffer(adapted_width, adapted_height);

  nv12toi420_scaler_.NV12ToI420Scale(
      y_plane, width, uv_plane, uv_width * 2, crop_width, crop_height,
      buffer->MutableDataY(), buffer->StrideY(),
      // Swap U and V, since we have NV21, not NV12.
      buffer->MutableDataV(), buffer->StrideV(), buffer->MutableDataU(),
      buffer->StrideU(), buffer->width(), buffer->height());

  OnFrame(VideoFrame(rotated_buffer, rotation, translated_camera_time_us));
}
```

**Modified Version:**

```
void AndroidVideoTrackSource::OnByteBufferFrameCaptured(const void* frame_data,
                                                        int length,
                                                        int width,
                                                        int height,
                                                        VideoRotation rotation,
                                                        int64_t timestamp_ns) {
  RTC_DCHECK(camera_thread_checker_.CalledOnValidThread());

  int64_t camera_time_us = timestamp_ns / rtc::kNumNanosecsPerMicrosec;
  int64_t translated_camera_time_us =
      timestamp_aligner_.TranslateTimestamp(camera_time_us, rtc::TimeMicros());

  int adapted_width;
  int adapted_height;
  int crop_width;
  int crop_height;
  int crop_x;
  int crop_y;

  if (!AdaptFrame(width, height, camera_time_us, &adapted_width,
                  &adapted_height, &crop_width, &crop_height, &crop_x,
                  &crop_y)) {
    return;
  }

  const uint8_t* y_plane = static_cast<const uint8_t*>(frame_data);
  const uint8_t* uv_plane = y_plane + width * height;
  const int uv_width = (width + 1) / 2;

  RTC_CHECK_GE(length, width * height + 2 * uv_width * ((height + 1) / 2));

  // Can only crop at even pixels.
  crop_x &= ~1;
  crop_y &= ~1;
  // Crop just by modifying pointers.
  y_plane += width * crop_y + crop_x;
  uv_plane += uv_width * crop_y + crop_x;

  rtc::scoped_refptr<I420Buffer> buffer =
      buffer_pool_.CreateBuffer(adapted_width, adapted_height);

  nv12toi420_scaler_.NV12ToI420Scale(
      y_plane, width, uv_plane, uv_width * 2, crop_width, crop_height,
      buffer->MutableDataY(), buffer->StrideY(),
      // Swap U and V, since we have NV21, not NV12.
      buffer->MutableDataV(), buffer->StrideV(), buffer->MutableDataU(),
      buffer->StrideU(), buffer->width(), buffer->height());

  // TODO: Comment out this line of code to apply custom code.
  // OnFrame(VideoFrame(buffer, rotation, translated_camera_time_us));

  // TODO: The custom code to rotate video frame before passing
  // to next layers of WebRTC.

  // Rotate I420 frame rotation degrees.
  // Value of the rotation is 90 or 270 based on camera orientation.
  rtc::scoped_refptr<I420Buffer> rotated_buffer =
      I420Buffer::Rotate(*buffer, rotation);

  // Make sure the I420 frame has valid side in portrait mode.
  rtc::scoped_refptr<I420Buffer> final_buffer =
      buffer_pool_.CreateBuffer(height, width);
  final_buffer->ScaleFrom(*rotated_buffer);

  // After rotating the I420 frame, set value of the rotation to 0.
  // This mean we do not want to rotate the frame in next layers anymore.
  rotation = kVideoRotation_0;

  // Pass processed frame to the next layers.
  OnFrame(VideoFrame(final_buffer, rotation, translated_camera_time_us));
}
```

Now my stream is displayed perfectly on Streaming Wowza Engine Player.

Comment: Hi @Son how did you edit webrtc source? I'm using react-native-webrtc module and i'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Thanks @Sao so did you finally replace libwebrtc.jar ?

Comment: Yeah, after you build the lib successfully then replace current webrtc lib in your project.

Comment: thank you, would you be able to share your lib with me. thanks a lot!

Comment: Would be grateful if you can help to share the update lib. I'm having hard time trying to figure out what to change. Thank  you

Comment: @PruthviRajNadimpalli Please give me your email.

Comment: rajprince.19@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciate your help

Comment: Check your email.